# Node.js module not communicating

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, asynchronous

I am in the process of teaching myself node.js by building a personal project. I am trying to follow best practices by splitting my code up into separate modules. However, I've run into a problem where one of my modules is communicating back to the caller module. I've used callback functions and events, but the caller module never gets anything back from the called module, unless the called module returns a value immediately. Please look at the below code and let me know what I'm missing:

blogs.controller.js (caller module)

```
var ImageParser = require('../../components/parsers/ImageParser.js');
.....
var imageParser = new ImageParser();
imageParser.on('imagesParsed', function(){
console.log('test)});
```

ImageParser.js (called module)

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

var ImageParser = function(){
    this.emit('imagesParsed');
};

util.inherits(ImageParser, EventEmitter);

module.exports = ImageParser;
```

Within the ImageParser function, I can listen for the event, but outside of it, I can't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You set up a handler for "imagesParsed" but the code emits an event called "imagesParse".

Comment: Also, emitting the event from inside the constructor doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It was just a typo here, though, not in my actual code.

Comment: Even when I emit the event from a method on the ImageParser, the caller module still doesn't hear anything.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found my answer in an answer to another question, answered by @linus-g-thiel
Also, thanks to @Pointy

Turns out I need to emit the event from a method, not the constructor, and the listener needs to be BEFORE the method call. It's working now.